# How to suppress mu4e warning messages?

Tags: mu4e, email, warning

**Q:** how do I suppress `mu4e` warnings about the update process?

I am using `mu4e` with `mbsync`.  Recently, the latter has started
to emit an error/warning message about losing track of messages.
When it does so, `mu4e` spits out a warning message:

```
[mu4e] Update process returned with non-zero exit code
```

That's normally fine, but it is annoying, especially as it spams
my echo area every time `mu4e` checks my email.

Until I figure out what the problem is with `mbsync`, I have to
tolerate the "losing track of messages" warning it gives.
However, I'd like to know how to tell `mu4e` to shut up about it
so it doesn't continue to alert me about non-zero exit codes.  How
do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Much simpler than I realized: just set
`mu4e-index-update-error-warning` to `nil`.

The docstring:

```
Whether to display warnings during the retrieval process.
This depends on the ‘mu4e-get-mail-command’ exit code.
```

Here's a little function to toggle the setting:

```
(defun mu4e-toggle-ignore-warnings ()
  "Toggle whether or not mu4e reports update process warnings to
echo area."
  (interactive)
  (setq mu4e-index-update-error-warning
        (not mu4e-index-update-error-warning)))
```